# Linux Bash: Variable to another variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed, variable, echo

i have this:

```
echo $MSG | sed -e $'s/;/\\\n/g'
```

I want to put the result of that sed in a new variable called $MSG2

Something like:

```
$MSG2=echo $MSG|sed -e $'s/;/\\\n/g'
```

How can i do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your task, you don't need pipelines or sed.  It can all be done much more efficiently using builtin `bash` commands like this:

```
NewMsg=${MSG//;/$'\n'}
```

`${MSG//;/$'\n'}` is an example of *pattern substitution*.  It replaces every occurrence of `;` with a newline character. The result is saved in the shell variable `NewMsg`.

As an example:

```
$ Msg='1;2;3'
$ NewMsg=${Msg//;/$'\n'}
$ echo "$NewMsg"
1
2
3
```

Notes:

1. It is best practice to use lower-case or mixed-case shell variables.  The system uses all caps for its variables and you don't want to accidentally overwrite one of them.
2. Unless you explicitly want *word splitting* and *pathname expansion* always put your shell variables in double-quotes.  Thus, when temped to use `echo $MSG`, use instead `echo "$MSG"`.
3. Also, unless you know what characters are going to be in the string that you are echoing, `echo` has problems and it is safer and more portable to use `printf '%s\n' "$MSG"`.  For more details, see Stéphane Chazelas' [very informative discussion of `echo` vs `printf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/53604).
4. Be aware that if you do use command substitution, `$(...)`, the shell will remove all trailing newlines.  While this is usually helpful, there are times when the change is unwanted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good point and your linked answer includes an impressive lot of information.  Thanks.  The answer is updated to mention `printf` and include that link.

Comment: While removing **one** trailing newline is _usually helpful_, removing the other ones is almost always unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign it to the variable like this:

```
MSG2=$(echo $MSG | sed -e $'s/;/\\n/g')
```

Comment: Or use `sed` with `y/;/\n/` which does not require `$'...'` and which is portable (or more simply `tr ';' '\n'` instead of `sed`).  Also remember to quote `$MSG` or the shell may expand glob patterns in its value.

Comment: `sed -e $'s/;/\\n/g'` is `sed -e 's/;/\n/g'` so is a non-portable variant of the OP's portable (in `bash`) `sed -e $'s/;/\\\n/g'`